# Can I put logical operators in document.querySelectorAll? If so, how?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, selector, selectors-api

Let's say I want to find all `div` elements and `span` inside `p`.

Is it possible to get all what I want in a single `querySelectorAll` invocation?

Conceptually it should be something like `document.querySelectorAll("div | p span")` (where <kbd>|</kbd> means **or**).

Comment: Can you put logical operators on CSS selectors?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("p div, p span")`

Comment: @RayonDabre That is wrong. That will select `span` elements inside `p` and all `div` elements throughout the DOM.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, Agreed!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes. You can use the same logical operators allowed in CSS:

OR: chain selectors with commas

```
document.querySelectorAll('div, p span');
// selects divs, and spans in ps
```

AND: chain selectors without whitespace

```
document.querySelectorAll('div.myClass');
// selects divs with the class "myClass"
```

NOT: `:not()`-selector

```
document.querySelectorAll('div:not(.myClass)');
// selects divs that do not have the class "myClass"
```