# Queryselectall for selecting invalid input types

Tags: javascript, html

For simplicity sake, I have the following html that I didn't write and I have no control over.

```
<input type="text" id="532523" name="safgafg">
<input type="text" id="453462" name="sdhfd">
<input type="text num" id="2354614" name="fghjsfga">
<textarea></textarea>
```

I am trying to write a script for our clerk that has to enter data into this web interface, so she can copy and paste data from excel over to the web interface.

Originally, all of the inputs have always been "text" so I have been able to use the following:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]').entries()
```

But I'm having trouble with how I can use queryselectall to get the "text num" and also a textarea. I tried to look it up on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) but it didn't have any advice on using logical operators, and I tried [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36544941/can-i-put-logical-operators-in-document-queryselectorall-if-so-how) on using logical operators but the following didn't have any effect:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text], input[type=text num], textarea').entries();
```

Comment: `input[type=text num]` isn't a thing

Comment: `type="text num"` is very invalid.

Comment: I said I didn't write the html, and I also cannot control it.

Comment: @zer00ne Unrecognized types are ignored and treated as text. This is what allows you to use things like `type="number"` with old browsers. But a selector still needs to include the invalid type to match the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put quotes around the value of the `type` attribute in your selector.

**Note: "text num" is not a valid value for the type attribute of an input.  The original selector without the quotes did not work because the value contains a space.**

```js
console.log([...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"], input[type="text num"], textarea')]);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="532523" name="safgafg">
<input type="text" id="453462" name="sdhfd">
<input type="text num" id="2354614" name="fghjsfga">
<textarea></textarea>
<div></div>
```