# How can I make the function querySelectorAll select a class AND a src at the same time?

Tags: javascript, dom, selectors-api

I've created the following code:

```js
const circle = document.querySelectorAll('[src = "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/734/734544.png"]')
const classTwo = document.querySelectorAll('.one')

const circleANDClassTwo = document.querySelectorAll('.one [src = "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/734/734544.png"]')

//console.log(circle)
//console.log(classTwo)
console.log(circleANDClassTwo)
```

```html
<img id="1" src="https://i.imgur.com/ZcGeIVz.png" class="one" style="width:50px;height:50px">
<img id="2" src="https://i.imgur.com/ZcGeIVz.png" class="one" style="width:50px;height:50px">
<img id="3" src="https://i.imgur.com/ZcGeIVz.png" class="one" style="width:50px;height:50px">
<img id="4" src="https://i.imgur.com/ZcGeIVz.png" class="one" style="width:50px;height:50px">
<img id="5" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/734/734544.png" class="one" style="width:50px;height:50px">
<img id="6" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/734/734544.png" class="one" style="width:50px;height:50px">
<img id="7" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/734/734544.png" class="two" style="width:50px;height:50px">
<img id="8" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/734/734544.png" class="two" style="width:50px;height:50px">
<img id="9" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/734/734544.png" class="two" style="width:50px;height:50px">
<img id="10" src="https://i.imgur.com/ZcGeIVz.png" class="two" style="width:50px;height:50px">
<img id="11" src="https://i.imgur.com/ZcGeIVz.png" class="two" style="width:50px;height:50px">
<img id="12" src="https://i.imgur.com/ZcGeIVz.png" class="two" style="width:50px;height:50px">
```

I know how to use the AND operator with the function `querySelectorAll` when it's selecting only specific tags and classes like described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36545002/14739472). But I didn't manage to make it filter a class AND a specific attribute at the same time. On my sample, I'd like to filter all elements that belong to the `class` `one` and that have a `src` `https://stackoverflow.com/a/36545002/14739472` (that would be the `id` 5 and the `id` 6)... I've tried using `.`, space, `,` but none of them work... I didn't find any example on how to do it when I'm specifying an attribute AND a class with `querySelectorAll`. How can I do it?

Comment: Just don't use any separator: `.one[src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/734/734544.png"]`

Comment: Gosh, I really spent some hours here because of that... Thanks, that works perfectly for me :)

Comment: These are the same selectors that you can use in CSS, maybe this helps in finding documentation and examples next time! (eg. search for `css select both class and attribute`)

Comment: @raylight Don’t guess. The selectors are [specified](//drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#overview) and [documented](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).