# After adding second element first element does not switch

Tags: javascript

I created function which create elements

```
function createElements(value) {
  //Create div .toggler
  const toggler = document.createElement('div');
  toggler.classList.add('toggler');

  //Create div .content
  const content = document.createElement('div');
  content.classList.add('content');

  //Append div .toggler in div .container
  container.append(toggler);

  //Append div .content in div .container
  container.append(content);

  toggler.innerText = 'Click me';
  content.innerText = value;
}
```

And function which should show and hide content if I'll click toggler 'Click me'

```
function toggleContent() {
  //Get created elements
  const togglers = document.querySelectorAll('.toggler'),
    contents = document.querySelectorAll('.content');

  //Toggle both div .active
  togglers.forEach((toggler, index) => {
    const content = contents[index];

    //Get div .content height
    const contentHeight = content.clientHeight + 'px';

    //Set div .content height
    content.style.height = '0px';

    //Toggle event
    toggler.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (!toggler.classList.contains('active')) {
        toggler.classList.add('active');
      } else {
        toggler.classList.remove('active');
      }

      if (!content.classList.contains('active')) {
        content.classList.add('active');
        content.style.height = contentHeight;
      } else {
        content.classList.remove('active');
        content.style.height = '0px';
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Put these both functions in event of button

```
//Create html elements and set value inner them event
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  createElements(input.value);
  toggleContent();

  //Clear input value
  input.value = '';
  //   console.log(input.value);
});
```

All works fine, but if I add second element, first element toggler does not work

```js
//Get html elements
const container = document.querySelector('.container'),
  input = document.querySelector('.input'),
  btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

function createElements(value) {
  //Create div .toggler
  const toggler = document.createElement('div');
  toggler.classList.add('toggler');

  //Create div .content
  const content = document.createElement('div');
  content.classList.add('content');

  //Append div .toggler in div .container
  container.append(toggler);

  //Append div .content in div .container
  container.append(content);

  toggler.innerText = 'Click me';
  content.innerText = value;
}

function toggleContent() {
  //Get created elements
  const togglers = document.querySelectorAll('.toggler'),
    contents = document.querySelectorAll('.content');

  //Toggle both div .active
  togglers.forEach((toggler, index) => {
    const content = contents[index];

    //Get div .content height
    const contentHeight = content.clientHeight + 'px';

    //Set div .content height
    content.style.height = '0px';

    //Toggle event
    toggler.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (!toggler.classList.contains('active')) {
        toggler.classList.add('active');
      } else {
        toggler.classList.remove('active');
      }

      if (!content.classList.contains('active')) {
        content.classList.add('active');
        content.style.height = contentHeight;
      } else {
        content.classList.remove('active');
        content.style.height = '0px';
      }
    });
  });
}

//Create html elements and set value inner them event
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  createElements(input.value);
  toggleContent();

  //Clear input value
  input.value = '';
  //   console.log(input.value);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
    <input type="text" class="input" />
    <button class="btn">add</button>
    
    <div class="container">
      <!-- <div class="toggler"></div>
      <div class="content"></div> -->
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "add second content"?

Comment: I mean second element, sorry ill fix it

Comment: So you mean adding a second line something like this into `createElements()`?
 `const contentB = document.createElement('div');`

Comment: @NathanWiles He means when user adds a second element on page. Run the code snippet, and try to add more than 1 element.

Comment: I mean on first element does not work toggleContent function after that I added second element. I can't understand why!

Comment: what `active` class is supposed to be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first toggler (and subsequent ones as you add more elements) stop working because of 2 reasons:

1. every time a new element is added you add another click listener to the existing elements (so when 2nd element is added, 1st element gets another click listener, this causes some weirdness later on)
2. every time a new element is added for every existing item you remember their `clientHeight` so if they are actually in a collapsed state, you will store `0px` to `contentHeight` so the new click handler will then be always using `0px` also for expanded state height. It would be better to toggle `display: none` and `display: block` (or inline or inline-block whichever you need)

I moved the click handler registration to the first function, in this way every created element gets only one click handler.

I removed the clientHeight/contentHeight logic and just added a CSS rule so that `.content` items are visible when `.active` and not visible otherwise.
So the change was this part in CSS

```
.content {
  display: none;
}

.content.active {
   display: block;
}
```

I kept the logic that when you add a new item it will collapse all existing items. I think that is what you had in you logic too, but let me know if you don't want that.

The change was in JS code

```
//Toggle both div .active
togglers.forEach((toggler, index) => {
    const content = contents[index];

    // I added this to keep the same logic you had before
    // if you would like to not collapse them, just remove the 2 lines
    toggler.classList.remove('active');
    content.classList.remove('active');
});
```

```js
//Get html elements
const container = document.querySelector('.container'),
  input = document.querySelector('.input'),
  btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

function createElements(value) {
  //Create div .toggler
  const toggler = document.createElement('div');
  toggler.classList.add('toggler');

  //Create div .content
  const content = document.createElement('div');
  content.classList.add('content');

  //Append div .toggler in div .container
  container.append(toggler);

  //Append div .content in div .container
  container.append(content);

  toggler.innerText = 'Click me';
  content.innerText = value;

  toggler.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (!toggler.classList.contains('active')) {
        toggler.classList.add('active');
      } else {
        toggler.classList.remove('active');
      }

      if (!content.classList.contains('active')) {
        content.classList.add('active');
      } else {
        content.classList.remove('active');
      }
    });
}

function toggleContent() {
  //Get created elements
  const togglers = document.querySelectorAll('.toggler'),
    contents = document.querySelectorAll('.content');

  //Toggle both div .active
  togglers.forEach((toggler, index) => {
    const content = contents[index];

    toggler.classList.remove('active');
    content.classList.remove('active');
  });
}

//Create html elements and set value inner them event
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  createElements(input.value);
  toggleContent();

  //Clear input value
  input.value = '';
  //   console.log(input.value);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
  display: none;
}

.content.active {
   display: block;
}
```

```html
    <input type="text" class="input" />
    <button class="btn">add</button>
    
    <div class="container">
      <!-- <div class="toggler"></div>
      <div class="content"></div> -->
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm a newbie to JS, could you please guide me on the first problem, which you described!

Comment: @levonogiy The first problem is fixed in the code above as well. The problem in your original code was that you called `toggler.addEventListener('click' ...` inside a `forEach` loop (this one `togglers.forEach((toggler, index) => ...`) so you added a duplicate listener to all existing elements every time the Add button was clicked. Would you like to know anything else about this?

Comment: Understand, ty very much!

Comment: @levonogiy Also see my last edit, I explained where the code actually changed.

Answer (score 1):

In your function `toggleContent()` you are adding a new event listener to **all** existing togglers every time you add a new element.

This means that when you add two elements, the first toggler will have two events, and both events would execute and cause unexpected behaviour.

One solution may be to add a new class to the togglers when adding the event listener to them, so you are sure that you are not appending more than one listener to the same element. Then, in your `document.querySelectorAll()` function you can use the [*not*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36545002/13615635) operator to exclude those elements that already have an event listener

```js
//Get html elements
const container = document.querySelector('.container'),
  input = document.querySelector('.input'),
  btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

function createElements(value) {
  //Create div .toggler
  const toggler = document.createElement('div');
  toggler.classList.add('toggler');

  //Create div .content
  const content = document.createElement('div');
  content.classList.add('content');

  //Append div .toggler in div .container
  container.append(toggler);

  //Append div .content in div .container
  container.append(content);

  toggler.innerText = 'Click me';
  content.innerText = value;
}

function toggleContent() {
  //Get created elements
  const togglers = document.querySelectorAll(
    '.toggler:not(.event-added)');   // using not operator
  const contents = document.querySelectorAll(
    '.content:not(.event-added)');   // using not operator

  //Toggle both div .active
  togglers.forEach((toggler, index) => {
    const content = contents[index];

    //Get div .content height
    const contentHeight = content.clientHeight + 'px';

    //Set div .content height
    content.style.height = '0px';

    //Toggle event
    toggler.addEventListener('click', () => {

      toggler.classList.add("event-added");    // Add new class
      content.classList.add("event-added");

      if (!toggler.classList.contains('active')) {
        toggler.classList.add('active');
      } else {
        toggler.classList.remove('active');
      }

      if (!content.classList.contains('active')) {
        content.classList.add('active');
        content.style.height = contentHeight;
      } else {
        content.classList.remove('active');
        content.style.height = '0px';
      }
    });
  });
}

//Create html elements and set value inner them event
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  createElements(input.value);
  toggleContent();

  //Clear input value
  input.value = '';
  //   console.log(input.value);
});
```

```css
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input" />
<button class="btn">add</button>

<div class="container">
  <!-- <div class="toggler"></div>
  <div class="content"></div> -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand your question...

```js
const
  container = document.querySelector('.container')
, input     = document.querySelector('.input')
, btn       = document.querySelector('.btn')
, contents  = []
  ;
btn.onclick = e =>
  {
  let inValue = input.value.trim()

  if (!inValue) return

  const
    toggler = document.createElement('div')  
  , content = document.createElement('div') 
    ;
  toggler.className = 'toggler'
  toggler.innerText = 'Click me'

  content.className   = 'content'
  content.textContent = inValue;

  container.append(toggler);
  container.append(content);

  contents.push(content)

  input.value = '' // clear input
  toggler.click()
  input.focus()
  }
container.onclick = e =>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('div.toggler')) return

  let nxtContent = e.target.nextElementSibling

  if (nxtContent.classList.toggle('active'))
    contents.forEach(c=>c.classList.toggle('active', c===nxtContent))
  }
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
.content {
  display: none;
  }
.content.active {
  display: block;
  }
.toggler {
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input" />
<button class="btn">add</button>

<div class="container">
  <!-- <div class="toggler"></div>
  <div class="content"></div> -->
</div>
```

You want to do something like that?

Comment: I already figured it out, but ty for your answer.

Comment: I'll try to use your example in my code.